# how to convert VarChar to integer?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sum

I have a time column which has been defined as VarChar , I can not change the column type to Integer because Integer does not recognize  the ":" between my numbers, now I need to use sum method to calculate how much time does a person work in my office, but I can not use sum method because VarChar can not get summed . how can I can convert VarChar to Integer and delete the ":" between numbers.

Comment: Use [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat) to convert the sql dates and find the difference

Comment: you don't need to sum anything, etc. Parse date from string, and compare it.

Answer (score 2):

First in SQLite, with the exception of an alias of the rowid column (a column defined specifically using `column_name INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`) any column type can store any type of value. So there would be no need to change the column type.

Second your could use `sum(replace(your_column,':','')`, to sum and replace the colon when extracting the data.

Third if date/times/date and times are stored in a recognised format you can easily add, subtract and manipulate dates and times [SQL As Understood By SQLite - Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

If you edit your question and provide your table schema(layout), example data, and the expected results. Then more comprehensive answer can be provided.

As a demo of the above consider :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS anycolumntypedemo;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS anycolumntypedemo (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY /* CAN ONLY HAVE INTEGER VALUE AS DATA TYPE MISMATCH ERROR */,
    col1 VARCHAR,
    col2 BLOB,
    col3 nrealyanythinggoestype
);
INSERT INTO anycolumntypedemo VALUES
    (null,100,100,100),
        (null,'FRED','BERT','HARRY'),
        (null,x'0102',datetime('now'),'')
;
SELECT *, replace(col2,':','') AS getridofcolons FROM anycolumntypedemo;
```

This :-

1. Deletes (**DROP**S) the table if it exists, for rerun-ability of the demo.
2. **CREATE**s the demo table with columns

   1. **id** an alias of the rowid
   2. **col1** as type VARCHAR (type affinity is the correct term)
   3. **col2** as type BLOB (byte[])
   4. **col3** as a really stupid type *but it works*
3. Inserts 3 rows,

   1. all with id being autogenerated as an integer
   2. the 1st row with col1-col3 having the value 100
   3. the 2nd row with col1-col3 having strings (TEXT)
   4. the 3rd row with col1 as a byte[] (2 bytes 01 and 02), col2 with the current date and time (format will be YYYY-DD-MM hh:mm:ss) and col3 as an empty string
4. Selects all columns plus and extra derived column that is the value of col2 except that **colons are removed**.

The resultant output being :-

[image]

- The red circled is how the SQLite Management Tool (Navicat) displays BLOB's.
- The yellow highlighted values shows the **colons removed** from the date and time.